# box2d light - the shadow is the same lighting of the color

Tags: libgdx, box2d, box2dlights

I am new to libGDX and Box2dlights i made a point light but there is a very weird problem the shadow is the same color of the point light  - this is so weird when my sprite cross the light range it casts a shadow with the same color of the point light

Comment: And maybe a screenshot for clarification...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting .setSoftnessLength to 0f setSoft(false) maybe add more light rays (50-100 is good enough in 80% of cases  )

Comment: 50-100 rays looks like a performance killer to me and I don't see any reason why it could help here...

Answer (score 0):

[how light behave when it has small number of rays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHvLc.png)
Sorry my drawing is awful. more rays = more accurate shadows. to keep good level of performance try to reduce ray length . and make ambient light more bright to fake light level. make sure x-ray disabled. set soft to false also is good for performance. because we don't have any code it is hard to guess what is going on. i am just suggesting